# Something's turning off my hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, shutdown, power-management

I have an Acer Aspire V3-771G laptop With Intel chipset and NVidia 650M Graphics, running Windows 8.1 pro. The laptop has 2 hard drive slots.

A few weeks ago I installed an SSD in my laptop. I freshly installed Windows 8.1 and put some of my frequently used programs on it. My old HDD is in the second internal slot, and contains some of my less used programs, large programs and lots of other data that I don't need frequently.

Here's the thing: although Windows power settings are set to NEVER turn off my hard drives, my HDD turns off frequently. Like, really frequently, if I don't touch it for just a minute or two, it turns off. This makes the simplest things like playing music or running programs off of it really slow, since the hard drive has to 'restart' all the time.

The SSD doesn't seem to have any issues. HD Tune Pro doesn't notice anything wrong with both drives (health status: OK).

So, if Windows Power Management isn't turning off my hard drives, what could be doing it?

EDIT: I don't think there's physical damage to the HDD, because when I leave CPUID HWmonitor running in the background, my HDD doesn't get shut down since it's being accessed constantly.

Comment: Define "turn off" for example if you playing music from the drive what happens? Does music stop and if it does what action do you need to take to resume it? Does it only happens when you are running on battery or also happens when you are plugged in?

Comment: Well, when for instance I use spotify and go from streaming a song from the internet to playing a song from my hard drive, the program hangs for a few seconds and I hear my hard disk turning on. When it's turned on, spotify starts playing. Also, my laptop is constandly in the wall, there's not even a battery installed.

Comment: Do you experience the same behavior when you try to browse a disk through explorer? for example you don't use your PC for some time than open explorer and try to navigate through the drive.

Comment: Yes, I do. I experience the problem with every program that tries to access the hard drive after some time (FL studio, Spotify, Explorer, Games, ...), unless I keep CPUID HWmonitor running.

Comment: Have you installed any third party software for drive management?

Comment: Have you looked at the Windows event log viewer to determine if that event is recorded?  That may point out what is happening.

Comment: Event logger gives me this (translated, my computer is configured in Dutch):

Info - UserModePowerService
Process C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (proces-id:2520) changed policy from {8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c} to{8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c}

Comment: seems like it sets the power plan from HIGH PERFOMANCE to HIGH PERFORMANCE.. not really helping.
I haven't installed any third party software, other than Intel drivers for the chipset.

Comment: Which device is being turned off?  If its the SSD have you tried to update the firmware on it?

Comment: In my question, I said the HDD turns off and the SSD keeps running fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Acer Customer Support the other day.

Apparently power settings only apply to the primary hard drive (where windows is installed). The standby policy of the other hard drives relies on instructions from BIOS or firmware.

KeepAliveHD is a lightweight tool that fixes that, and (as the name implies) prevents the hard drive from going to sleep mode.

http://keepalivehd.codeplex.com/